# Настройка работы API со space-track.org через прокси (или как задать нужный прокси и сертификат к нему)

Tags: python-3.x, api, requests

Есть рабочая программа, которая получает данные с https://www.space-track.org/.
Весь смысл заключается в строках:

```
session = requests.Session() #создание сессии
resp = session.post(urlLog, data=siteCred) #авторизация на сайте
resp = session.get(url) #уже непосредственное получение данных по нужным ссылкам (по номерам спутников)
```

На нормальном интернете, всё работает прекрасно. Но теперь нужно организовать работу проги через урезанный рабочий инет, имея данные прокси.
Я предполагаю, что прокси и верификацию (или её отсутствие) нужно прописывать в post (при авторизации), а не в get (где уже идёт получение данных).

На данный момент метод `resp = session.post(urlLog, data=siteCred, proxies=proxies, verify=False)` не работает. Выдаёт предупреждение `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:845: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings  InsecureRequestWarning)`

Для примера, при попытке получить данные по спутнику LCS 1 (с номером 1361) выбрасывает ошибку `HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.space-track.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /basicspacedata/query/class/tle_latest/ORDINAL/1/NORAD_CAT_ID/1361/orderby/TLE_LINE1%20ASC/format/3le (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0xb6b47f0c>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))`

Таймауты не помогают. Вариант через HTTPProxyAuth тоже. Способ с игнором ворнингов через `urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)` сам ворнинг убирает, но ошибка [Errno 111] остаётся.

Если аргумент `verify=` вообще убрать, получаю: `[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:720)` Также вопрос, какой правильный формат у прокси? Логин:пасс@Прокси:порт?

Где искать источники ошибок?

---

Upd. Коллеги подсказали, что нужно прописывать местный файл сертификат. Он есть, в формате .cer. (Какой формат в принципе подходит? В сети видела примеры, где нужен формат .pem. Перевести из .cer в .pem с помощью openssl мне не удалось) Если в post указывать дополнительный пункт `cert='самСертификат.cer'`, то выдаёт ошибку `[SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:2964)`, если его указать в `verify=`, то та же самая [Errno 111] выходит. В чём может быть косяк?

Upd 2. Т.к. на работе много чего урезано, нет доступа ко многим полезным библиотекам питона. Например, я натыкаюсь на варианты с использованием SmartConnectNoSSL из pyVim.connect, но тоже не могу их проверить из-за отсутствия возможности поставить pyVim.

---

Буду рада, если подскажете, какие ещё варианты стоит проверить и попробовать. Или как корректно использовать уже найденные.

Comment: openssl x509 -inform der -in certificate.cer -out certificate.pem
===-------->
см https://www.httpcs.com/en/ssl-converter

Comment: Я уже пробовала этот вариант. Выдаёт ошибку: 
`unable to load certificate
3073283840:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1129:`

`3073283840:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:289:Type=X509`
Здесь написано, что можно просто переименовать в .pem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14191468/openssl-encoding-errors-while-converting-cer-to-pem) - не сработало.

Comment: Также, по примеру отсюда (https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#client-side-certificates) пыталась в cert= закинуть помимо сертификата ещё и ключ (вытянутый из корня дебиана, но он скорее всего не специфичный-рабочий, а какой-то дефолтный). Лезет ошибка: `[X509: KEY_VALUES_MISMATCH] key values mismatch (_ssl.c:2964)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена. Прокси был прописан в неверном формате. (`"https": "https://"` и `"ftp": "ftp://"`, вместо `"https": "http://"` и `"ftp": "http://"`). Закидывать нужно было не аргументами в post и get, а вообще задавать как `session.proxies =` . Сертификат не нужен. Верификацию убирать через `verify=False`, ворнинги через:

```
from urllib3 import disable_warnings, exceptions
disable_warnings(exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
```